# Pytorch find the matching 2x2 tensor in a batch of 2x2 tensors

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a `2x2` reference tensor and a batch of candidate `2x2` tensors. I would like to find the closest candidate tensor to the reference tensor by summed euclidean distance over the identically indexed (except for the batch index) elements.

For example:

```
ref = torch.as_tensor([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
candidates = torch.rand(100, 2, 2)
```

I would like to find the `2x2` tensor `index` in `candidates` that minimizes:

```
(ref[0][0] - candidates[index][0][0])**2 + 
(ref[0][1] - candidates[index][0][1])**2 + 
(ref[1][0] - candidates[index][1][0])**2 + 
(ref[1][1] - candidates[index][1][1])**2
```

Ideally, this solution would work for arbitrary dimension reference tensor of size `(b, c, d, ...., z)` and an arbitrary `batch_size` of candidate tensors with equal dimensions to the reference tensor `(batch_size, b, c, d,..., z)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on @ndrwnaguib's answer, it should be rather:

```
dist = torch.cdist( ref.float().flatten().unsqueeze(0), candidates.flatten(start_dim=1))
print(torch.square( dist ))
torch.argmin( dist )
```

---

```
tensor([[23.3516, 21.8078, 25.5247, 26.3465, 21.3161, 17.7537, 24.1075, 22.4388,
         22.7513, 16.8489]])

tensor(9)
```

other options, worth noting:

```
torch.square(ref.float()- candidates).sum( dim=(1,2) )
```

---

```
tensor([[23.3516, 21.8078, 25.5247, 26.3465, 21.3161, 17.7537, 24.1075, 22.4388,
         22.7513, 16.8489]])
```

---

```
diff = ref.float()- candidates
torch.einsum( "abc,abc->a" ,diff, diff)
```

---

```
tensor([[23.3516, 21.8078, 25.5247, 26.3465, 21.3161, 17.7537, 24.1075, 22.4388,
         22.7513, 16.8489]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so in the more generic case with a reference of shape (a,b,c,....,z) and a batch of candidates with shape (batch_size,a,b,c,...z), the answer should be: dist = torch.cdist(ref.float().reshape(-1, (a\*b\*c\*...*z), candidates.reshape(-1, (a\*b\*c\*...*z))
print(torch.square( dist ))
torch.argmin( dist )?

Comment: It's fine, may be more elegant: `dist = torch.cdist( ref.float().flatten().unsqueeze(0), candidates.flatten(start_dim=1))`, edited.